# JSON .append @Html.Partial

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

While creating an order table, plus sign is needed, which adds a new row to the order. The first row of the table is always there. The problem is the first field which is an Html.Partial view and it handles a dropdown for all the selectable items.

The question: how can I append the @Html.Partial to the JSON function?
The problem: the @ sign.

```
function addOrderRow() {
        $("#btnAddOrderRow").click(function () {
              var newRow = '<tr style="height:50px;"><td class="col-md-6"><div class="row"><div id="SupplierItems" class="col-md-6">' +
                    '@Html.Partial("SupplierItems", Model)' +
                    '</div><div class="col-md-6"><input id="Description" type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100%" /></div></div></td><td class="col-md-3"><input id="Partnumber" type="text" style="width:100%" class="form-control" /></td><td class="col-md-2"><div class="form-inline"><strong>£&nbsp;</strong><input id="Cost" type="number" min="0" step="0.01" style="width:93%" class="form-control text-right" /></div></td><td class="col-md-1"><input id="Quantity" type="number" min="1" step="1" class="form-control text-center" value="1" style="width:100%" /></td><td class="col-md-1 text-center"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
              $("#orderTable > tbody:last-child").append(newRow);
        })
  };
```

If I escape the @ with an @ the function simply puts the @Html.Partial("SupplierItems", Model) text into the relevant `<td>`.

Comment: If you want to load a Partial View on Click of a Button in jQuery you will have to use Ajax to load it.

Answer (score 0):

You can render the view into a variable and then use that to add the row i.e.

```
var view = '@Html.Raw(@Html.Partial('Your partial'))';
```

Then use string concatenation to add the view

```
function addOrderRow() {
    var view = '@Html.Raw(@Html.Partial("SupplierItems", Model))';
    $("#btnAddOrderRow").click(function () {
          var newRow = '<tr style="height:50px;"><td class="col-md-6"><div class="row"><div id="SupplierItems" class="col-md-6">' +
                view +
                '</div><div class="col-md-6"><input id="Description" type="text" class="form-control" style="width:100%" /></div></div></td><td class="col-md-3"><input id="Partnumber" type="text" style="width:100%" class="form-control" /></td><td class="col-md-2"><div class="form-inline"><strong>£&nbsp;</strong><input id="Cost" type="number" min="0" step="0.01" style="width:93%" class="form-control text-right" /></div></td><td class="col-md-1"><input id="Quantity" type="number" min="1" step="1" class="form-control text-center" value="1" style="width:100%" /></td><td class="col-md-1 text-center"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
          $("#orderTable > tbody:last-child").append(newRow);
    })
};
```

Note this creates a static view which will render the same for every added row, I've found that some views are dependent on the Ids given to `Inputs` especially when using `ModelBinding`

Comment: Thanks @3dd, but the console reports: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  
The value of the view is:
var view = <select class="form-control" id="SupplierItems" name="SupplierItems" size="1" style="width: 100%;"><option value="">Select an Item</option>
</select>

Comment: The `@Html.Raw(@Html.Partial('Your partial'))` part should be in '' I've update my ans

Comment: Ok now the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: You need to remove all the newline characters from the view string, juts seeing if I can find the code for that quickly

Comment: the problem is with the view(html.raw) variable.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but try `var view = '@Html.Raw(@Html.Partial('Your partial')).replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")';`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer to the original question is:

```
var view = String.raw`@Html.Partial("SupplierItems", Model)`;
```

Mind the mark, which is not **'** !

But this is not helping me, because the partial view contains another `<script>` which messes up the page. I need to find a workaround. Question answered.